# Notifying clients about an event via DRF

Tags: django

I want to know if there really is a way of notifying clients about a certain event, VIA Djangorestframework. I know it can be achieved with websockets via channels, but I couldn't find any material that explains everything in a step by step process. If anyone can help me than thanks already.

Comment: i think the term that you looking for is `push notifications`. DRF is apis that a client use to call to your server and not the other way around

Comment: yes but I want the other way around. I just want to notify my client about the changes in the real time. How can this be possible?

Comment: are your client an app ? you can implement `push notification`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I find the solution. 
Actually I am using django rest framework(DRF) and django channels. What I wanted to achieve was to send message to a particular user and not to broadcast it in a group, by the api request. That is of course, a call from asynchronous code.

You can achieve this by sending message to specific channels as mentioned in django channels official [docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#channel-layers).

This is possible because whenever client joins the group, it is automatically assigned a channel that can uniquely identify that client. So what we need is that we save that channel into the database and whenever required, get it from database, as specified [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#synchronous-functions). You can save the channel to the database like [so](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#single-channels)

I hope this was helpful.